# How to put SOAP request and SOAP response in Log file in @EndPoint annotated class file

Tags: web-services, spring, tomcat, soap, websphere

I am using this bean code to log request and response to the log file

```
<bean
class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor">
   <property name="logRequest" value="true" />
   <property name="logResponse" value="true" />
</bean>
```

This works fine in the TOMCAT Application Server for logging SOAP Request and SOAP Response as it enters and leaves the @EndPoint class but not in the case of WebSphere Application Server V8.0. Is there any other method to put SOAP Request and SOAP response to the log file in SPRING-WS.

Answer (score 0):

There is other way. See the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/common.html#logging).

Anyway, why `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor` is not working with WebSphere? I have not experience with WebSphere but it could happen that your log configuration is being overwritten by the server one. Take a look to the server log configuration.